# NopCommerce 2.80 Configuring Multiple taxes for Canada

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce

I'm trying to figure out how to apply multiple taxes to my products. 
As you may have guess i'm from Quebec Canada, and my client has a strict requirement for this.

I saw this code in the 2.8 version

```
@if (Model.DisplayTaxRates && Model.TaxRates.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var taxRate in Model.TaxRates)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="cart-total-left">
                <span class="nobr">
                @string.Format(T("ShoppingCart.Totals.TaxRateLine").Text, taxRate.Rate)
                            :</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cart-total-right">
                <span class="nobr">
                    @taxRate.Value
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

in the CalculateTaxResult

is there a way for me to be able to show each tax and the total ?

How do I configure this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't supported. when they say multiple taxes, they mean the possibility to set a different tax per item and not multiple taxes per item.

changes to the coded need to be done to fake multiple taxes per item.